# Fixing [god] and [gods] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-deletion, tag-synonyms

The [god](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god) and [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) tags seem to be a little unnecessary. At the very least, they are redundant with respect to each other. Also, as has been discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/usability-of-a-word-gods) I'm not even sure if these words make any sense to use on our site.

Simply put, the tags are synonyms, and on top of that, they're very ambiguous.

Perhaps we need a [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) tag for questions referring to any arbitrary mortal deities and refer to any specific gods with individual tags like the [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) tag.

It might also be helpful to have a tag to refer to the supreme deity, but since everyone interprets the identity and name of that diety differently, I'm frankly not sure what we would call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now mapped all the questions with the tag <s>[god](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god)</s> with [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) and now the [god](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god) is a synonym of [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods).

*Perhaps we need a [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) tag for questions referring to any arbitrary mortal deities and refer to any specific gods with individual tags like the [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) tag.*

I wouldn't agree to this. [As I mentioned in another answer before,](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/answering-and-questioning-format-mythological-names-usage), word *devas* is not a generalized term used worldwide. Not only that, if you are making a tag of *devas* then you will need to create more tags such as *devi*, *mata*, *rakshasa* etc... which will further create a mess if tagged wrongly.

I agree that *gods* is too general, some may say that we shouldn't have that tag at all but we don't talk about gods only, we talk about culture, religion, practices, tradition etc, so in a way, [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) tag is perfectly fine according to me and need no further modifications.

If you want, I can create synonyms for you, like [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) is a synonym to [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) and so on but need some solid references before I do that.

Comment: I personally think it makes sense for [tag:devas] and [tag:gods] to be synonyms, since if we're going with the plural form of the latter, it really ought to encapsulate *Devas* in its intended meaning.

Comment: @Akshay Great, will wait for few comments from other users and will take necessary action or you can request the synonym by asking another question which will be much better to do so.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I would rather suggest to remove GODS tag, it states multiplicity, inplace GOD holds good.